# Swift 4.1 - Subclass UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimage, swift4.1

I get `Overriding non-@objc declarations from extensions is not supported` error when subclass UIImage with custom init after upgrading to Swift 4.1

```
class Foo: UIImage {

    init(bar: String) { }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // Overriding non-@objc declarations from extensions is not supported
    required convenience init(imageLiteralResourceName name: String) {
        fatalError("init(imageLiteralResourceName:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: UIImage is not for subclassing. Try composition instead of inheritance

Answer (score 5):

```
extension UIImage {

    /// Creates an instance initialized with the given resource name.
    ///
    /// Do not call this initializer directly. Instead, initialize a variable or
    /// constant using an image literal.
    required public convenience init(imageLiteralResourceName name: String)
}
```

This init method is declared in the extension of the `UIImage` class.

> The error pretty much says that if a function is declared in the extension than it can't be overridden in this way

```
class Foo: UIImage {

}

extension Foo {
    convenience init(bar :String) {
        self.init()
    }
}

var temp = Foo(bar: "Hello")
```

You could try to achieve the desired result in this way.

Comment: It does not work

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be caused by the `init(bar:)` designed initializer, if you convert it to a convenience one, then the class will compile:

```swift
class Foo: UIImage {

    convenience init(bar: String) { super.init() }

    // no longer need to override the required initializers
}
```

Seems that once you add a designated initializer (aka a non-convenience one), Swift will also enforce overrides for all required initializers from the base class. And for `UIImage` we have one that lives in an extension (not sure how it got there, likely was auto-generated, as myself wasn't able to add a required initializer in an extension). And you run into the compiler error in discussion.